# How to add javadocs to eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Where to add this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17412_01/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html

so, when I highlight a word in eclipse ide, I will get the help.

Answer (score 13):

To add Javadoc to Eclipse:

- [download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-doc-downloads.html) as many Javadoc packages as you want (they should be in `zip` or `jar` archives).
- Open your Eclipse preferences, and navigate to `Java -> Installed JREs`. Click on the default JRE you use, and click the `Edit` button on the right.
- In the window that pops up, click `Add External JARs` in the right column, and navigate to where you have the archives saved (you may want to save them somewhere out-of-the-way because if you delete the archives, your Javadoc won't work anymore).
- Select the archives, and click `Open`. This should recognize the Javadoc archives and help you with code-completion and documentation (you may have to restart your IDE for this to take effect).

You can find Java SE development kit 7 Documentation [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html)

**You didn't specify what operating system you were on, so each OS may vary slightly.*

Comment: I can't find the jsr118 docs

Comment: and i use windows xp

Comment: @mark It doesn't look like Oracle provides a downloadable Javadoc for the MIDP2.0 spec, only the HTML docs posted on their site.

Comment: Note that you don't need to extract the `zip` file, just add it in!

Comment: I get a strange message about "index.html" or "location-path" cannot be found in the javadoc archive, yet index.html is clearly in the root of the archive.

Answer (score 7):

Right Click the JAR file in **Project Explorer** -> **Properties** -> From the left pane choose **Javadoc Location** -> enter the URL of your jar documentation.

Generally you can Google for: `javadoc lib-name` and then pickup the URL of the first site suggested by Google - going up a level.

For example Google returned this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html
so by going up one level, I mean:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/

Answer (score 2):

1. Download de documentation of de java API you want to add
2. Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Installed JRE
3. Click on the jre > Edit
4. In the edit jre window > click on the .jar to expand the library
5. Click on Javadoc location > click button Javadoc Location on the right
6. Check Javadoc in archive > Browse > select the .zip where you downloaded the documentation (no need for extraction)
7. On Path Within Archive click con Browse > Select the "api" file where index.html is localted
8. Click on validate to check if everything is correct

Enjoy coding!